# Code working in UNIX but not in windows

Tags: python, wxpython

I have written a small bit of code in wxpython in which the splitter window is used to split the dialog box and one panel has custom tree ctrl and the other has static box.
This code was working fine in Fedora and ubuntu, but in Windows the dialog box is appearing empty.

Main code:

```py
wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, 6, 'Filters',size = (500,600) )
    self.splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, -1)
    leftPanel = wx.Panel(self.splitter, -1)
    leftBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.__tree = TreeFilter(leftPanel, 1)
    leftBox.Add(self.__tree, -1, wx.GROW)
    self.__tree.Bind(CT.EVT_TREE_ITEM_CHECKED, self.checked)
    leftPanel.SetSizer(leftBox)

    rightPanel = wx.Panel(self.splitter, -1)
    rightBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.display = wx.StaticText(rightPanel, -1, '', style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
    rightBox.Add(self.display, -1, wx.GROW)


    btnsizer = wx.StdDialogButtonSizer()
    btn = wx.Button(rightPanel, wx.ID_OK)
    btn.SetDefault()
    btnsizer.AddButton(btn)

    btn = wx.Button(rightPanel, wx.ID_CANCEL)
    btnsizer.AddButton(btn)
    btnsizer.Realize()
    rightBox.Add(btnsizer, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, 5)
    rightPanel.SetSizer(rightBox)

    self.splitter.SplitVertically(leftPanel, rightPanel)
    self.Centre()
```

where TreeFilter is a custom tree ctrl.
Please help me fixing the problem

Comment: Is anything displayed when you get rid of the custom tree control?

Comment: Nothing is displayed, absolutely empty dialog box is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have the splitter itself in a sizer that's set to expand. On my screen, you can see a little box all scrunched up in the left hand corner, so I knew something like that was happening.

Here's an example that works for me:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyTreeCtrl(wx.TreeCtrl):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.TreeCtrl.__init__(self, parent, id)


########################################################################
class TestDlg(wx.Dialog):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""

        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, 6, 'Filters',size = (500,600) )
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, -1)
        leftPanel = wx.Panel(self.splitter, -1)
        leftBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.tree = MyTreeCtrl(leftPanel, 1)

        self.root = self.tree.AddRoot("The Root Item")
        self.tree.SetPyData(self.root, None)
        for x in range(15):
            child = self.tree.AppendItem(self.root, "Item %d" % x)
            self.tree.SetPyData(child, None)
        self.tree.Expand(self.root)

        leftBox.Add(self.tree, -1, wx.GROW)
        #self.__tree.Bind(CT.EVT_TREE_ITEM_CHECKED, self.checked)
        leftPanel.SetSizer(leftBox)

        rightPanel = wx.Panel(self.splitter, -1)
        rightBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.display = wx.StaticText(rightPanel, -1, '', style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
        rightBox.Add(self.display, -1, wx.GROW)

        btnsizer = wx.StdDialogButtonSizer()
        btn = wx.Button(rightPanel, wx.ID_OK)
        btn.SetDefault()
        btnsizer.AddButton(btn)

        btn = wx.Button(rightPanel, wx.ID_CANCEL)
        btnsizer.AddButton(btn)
        btnsizer.Realize()
        rightBox.Add(btnsizer, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, 5)
        rightPanel.SetSizer(rightBox)

        self.splitter.SplitVertically(leftPanel, rightPanel)
        self.Centre()
        mainSizer.Add(self.splitter, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    dlg = TestDlg()
    dlg.Show()
    dlg.Destroy()
    app.MainLoop()
```